# Checkbox after click has only ::after

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Could someone help with checkbox issue which looked very simple, but get stacked.
Namely, checkbox which is not clicked looks like in HTML:

```
<label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"> Bonus la aniversare
  <input type="checkbox" 
  name="bonus_aniversare" value="1">
  <span></span>
   </label>
```

After click only difference is added **::after**, just check below HTML:

```
<label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"> Bonus la aniversare
  <input type="checkbox" 
  name="bonus_aniversare" value="1">
  <span>
   ::after
  </span>
   </label>
```

Found element (span) easily, but how can I add option when checkbox has been clicked?

```
String chosenSelection2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='tab_promotii']/div/div[4]/div/label/span"))
```

Did no have so far that case when only added **::after** and nothing else.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `add option when checkbox has been clicked`?

Comment: @DebanjanB I meant, after click on checkbox (confirm checkbox).